# c++ reinterpret_cast char to int* / adjacent bits are repeatedly set as 1100

Tags: c++, char, integer, bit, reinterpret-cast

Why does the second example find 1100 instead of 0000 after storing the address in the int pointer and then reading the adjacent bits?

**Example 1:**

```
char c = 'a';
int val = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&c);
```

val = 97 or 0110 0001

---

**Example 2:**

```
char c = 'a';
int* iptr = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&c);
int val = *iptr;
```

val = -858993567 or 1100 1100 | 1100 1100 | 1100 1100 | 0110 0001

Comment: (a) this is [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub); (b) [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: A `char` is typically 8 bits, and an `int` 32 bits. By reading the bits that are not part of the `char` value, you effectively go out of bounds of the memory for the variable `c` and have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: My crystal ball says this software is compiled in debug mode in Visual Studio, which often fills unused memory with repeating patterns, to help you notice that you are accidentally using unused memory.

Comment: @user253751 I compared the debug build on VS with the release build. There is indeed a difference. In the release build the phenomenon does not happen. Thats a good hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both have undefined behavior, generally already because accessing a `char` through a `int` pointer is an aliasing violation.

Even if that was allowed, the size of `int` will almost certainly be larger than that of `char` and trying to read an adjacent byte of a variable clearly causes undefined behavior.

And even further, the alignment of a `char` variable is probably not guaranteed to be large enough for an `int`.

All in all, it is wrong to expect any particular output from the programs.

In addition, @user253751 points out that the number pattern (1100) is generated in Visual Studio debug build. In the release build, this pattern is not set.

Answer (score 0):

The **problem** is that you're **typecasting** a `char*` to an `int*` and then dereferencing that `int*` which leads to **undefined behavior**.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior. The program may just crash.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB. The program may just crash.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>